# "No Matching Function for Call" when referencing function in class

Tags: c++, websocket, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to get an ESP8266 WebSocketsServer instance working with a Scheduler, but I can't get it to compile with an onEvent function. In the setup, I'm calling

`webSocket.onEvent(std::bind(&WebServer::webSocketEvent, this));`.

`WebServer` is the class, and `webSocketEvent` is defined as

`void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {...}`

Here's the full compile error log:

```
sketch_nov20a.ino: In member function 'virtual void WebServer::setup()':

sketch_nov20a:25: error: no matching function for call to 'WebSocketsServer::onEvent(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (WebServer::*)(unsigned char, WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int), WebServer* const>::type)'

       webSocket.onEvent(std::bind(&WebServer::webSocketEvent, this));

                                                                    ^

sketch_nov20a.ino:25:68: note: candidate is:

In file included from sketch_nov20a.ino:3:0:

...\Arduino\libraries\WebSockets\src/WebSocketsServer.h:58:14: note: void WebSocketsServer::onEvent(WebSocketsServer::WebSocketServerEvent)

         void onEvent(WebSocketServerEvent cbEvent);

              ^

...\Arduino\libraries\WebSockets\src/WebSocketsServer.h:58:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (WebServer::*)(unsigned char, WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int), WebServer* const>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (WebServer::*)(unsigned char, WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>(WebServer*)>}' to 'WebSocketsServer::WebSocketServerEvent {aka std::function<void(unsigned char, WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>}'
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Be so kind and post a [mcve]. It seems `onEvent` does not accept the result of `std::bind`, but it's hard to know without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: tried construction std::function and the passing it...?

    std::function<void(unsigned char, WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)> func = std::bind(...);
    webSocket.onEvent(func);

Implicit conversion should work, but maybe the explicit construction gives u some extra information in the error msg.

Answer (score 2):

`std::bind()` needs to explicitly be told to pass on the arguments from when it's helper is called to the original function. More or less placeholders may be needed depending on the number of arguments in the function.

To fix this, the call needs to be changed from

```
webSocket.onEvent(std::bind(&WebServer::webSocketEvent, this));
```

to

```
webSocket.onEvent(std::bind(&WebServer::webSocketEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4));
```